# Error in uploading the Large video over 100MB on youtube via php youtube Google api v3

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am facing the issue when I upload video who has size more than 100MB  on youtube via Google php APi v3. It is working fine for the small video less than 100mb.I have followed the tutorial https://www.domsammut.com/code/php-server-side-youtube-v3-oauth-api-video-upload-guide

This is the error I am getting for the Larger video

```
      Warning: filesize(): stat failed for uploads/20150618_112657.mp4  

             in/home/n001pr5/public_html/youtube2/upload.phpon line 99

       Warning: fopen(uploads/20150618_112657.mp4): failed to open      stream: No such file or directory in/home/n001pr5/public_html/youtube2      /upload.phpon line 105

        Warning: feof() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean   given in/home/n001pr5/public_html/youtube2/upload.phpon line 106

 Warning: fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given      in/home/n001pr5/public_html/youtube2/upload.phpon line 107
Caught Google service Exception 400 message is Error calling PUT    https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?part=status%2Csnippet&uploadType=resumable&   upload_id=AEnB2UrMv5ueozrFuP7QtiHqcjuekuOmvxBEAh9n1fBHXxf4BrKlYW3L786j8Dhc1EG    9YUYD71DB3Y46X4Q8ENmXKY4VkWuzcg: (400) Failed to parse Content-Range   header.Stack trace is #0 /home/n001pr5/public_html/youtube2/api/src/Google/Http/MediaFileUpload.php(183):                                    Google_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(Google_Http_Request),      Object(Google_Client)) #1 /home/n001pr5/public_html/youtube2/upload.php(108): Google_Http_MediaFileUpload->nextChunk(false) #2 {main}    Status: success
```

Comment: Have you verified your account so that you can upload videos longer than 15 minutes? See [here](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/71673?hl=en).

Comment: yes, I have verified that. Actually now I have found the problem. The problem is in my uploading script it is not uploading video more than 128 mb to my uploads folder. Can you help me in this? I had followed this tutorial http://tutorialzine.com/2013/05/mini-ajax-file-upload-form/ . i have increased the size to 1G  by adding the line 
   php_value upload_max_filesize 1G
    php_value post_max_size 1G
   php_value max_execution_time 20000
       php_value max_input_time 20000
In my .htaccess file. But no luck!

Comment: Try setting your max sizes in megabytes (M) instead of gigabytes. Also, you might have to comment out `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` if you have them in your php.ini file and make sure they're set only in .htaccess. Lastly, see if it setting `upload_max_filesize` > `post_max_Size` makes a difference.

Comment: Thanks for your response I have already done these things. Actually the problem is in my host. It is a shared host. I have used the vps and everything work like carm